# c++ template function overlading argument deduction with const argument

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I am having the following setup:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T& t);
void foo(const int& t);

void f()
{
    int i;
    foo(i); //Unresolved reference to "void foo<int>(int &)"
    foo(const_cast<const int&>(i)); //Unresolved reference to "void foo(int const &)"
}
```

In the first call to foo, the compiler tries to call the template version, since the argument of the non-template one does not match the type of **i**. In the second call the non-template version is called. I am using the Microsoft C++ compiler version 10. Is this standard behavior? If the type is not exactly matched, even if it only has a const modifier, then the template function is called?

EDIT: I know those two functions don't have definition, I am just pointing out what the linker complains about, to make it more clear what the compiler wants to call.

Comment: "Unresolved reference" is how the linker tells you that you *declared* something, but never *defined* it.

Comment: Where you have the definition of the function template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this standard behavior? If the type is not exactly matched, even if it only has a const modifier, then the template function is called?

Yes,  that is well-defined by the Standard.

If there is no EXACT match, the template is used, because instantiated template version is always a *better* match than the one which requires conversion (even be it `int &` to `int const&` conversion).

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, this behavior is correct according to the C++11 Standard.

In the first case, the argument is a reference to a non-`const` integer. Both overloads are viable to resolve this call, but the function template allows a perfect match, while the non-template overload requires a qualification conversion.

In the second case, both are a perfect match, but one of the overloads is **not** a function template, and therefore it is a better candidate than the function template. Per § 13.3.3/1, in fact:

> Given these definitions, **a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function
>   F2 if** for all arguments i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and then
>
> — for some argument j, ICSj(F1) is a better conversion sequence than ICSj(F2), or, if not that,
>
> — the context is an initialization by user-defined conversion (see 8.5, 13.3.1.5, and 13.3.1.6) and the
>   standard conversion sequence from the return type of F1 to the destination type (i.e., the type of the
>   entity being initialized) is a better conversion sequence than the standard conversion sequence from
>   the return type of F2 to the destination type. [ ... ] or, if not that,
>
> — **F1 is a non-template function and F2 is a function template specialization**, or, if not that,
>
> — [...]

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void foo(T& t) {}
void foo(const int& t){}

void f() 
{
    int i;
    foo(i); //Unresolved reference to "void foo<int>(int &)"
    foo(const_cast<const int&>(i)); //Unresolved reference to "void foo(int const &);
}

int main()
{
    f();
}
```